# Не работают стили для Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<Menu Background="Transparent">
            <MenuItem Header="Файл">
                <MenuItem Header="Создать проект"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Открыть проект"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Экспорт"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Закрыть проект"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Выход"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Проект"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Сборка"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Параметры"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Справка"/>
</Menu>
```

Стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="ContextMenu"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

Вопрос: почему не применяется стиль???

Comment: Вы не определили ключ/имя стиля, но пытаетесь ссылаться на `MetroMenuItem`.

Comment: Там опечатка, ссылается на MetroContextMenu

Comment: И я стили определил:
<Style TargetType="ContextMenu" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}"/>

Comment: А где у вас ContextMenu в вопросе?

Comment: При нажатие на MenuItem вызывается контекстное меню с другими menuitem. Возможно, я не к тому объекту пишу стиль?

Comment: Я в вашей разметке не вижу ContextMenu, с чего вы взяли, что оно само создастся? Пишите стиль для MenuItem

Comment: Написал, вот это выглядит - https://ibb.co/mOoSLy
Мне нужно убрать окантовку и изменить цвет контекстного меню просто

Comment: У вас нет на скрине контекстного меню, только обычное. Это вам понятно?

Comment: На скрине у меня меню и выпадающие меню. Мне нужно задать стиль выпадающему меню

Comment: Это MenuItem, а не ContextMenu

Comment: Мне нужно убрать белую окантовку у выпадающего меню